# Class sent to Post Action is null

Tags: asp.net-core, http-post

I'm working on a view that presents all the records of class (`Machine`) where some of their properties could be updated.

For this, the view is working with an IEnumerable. These are the Get and Post methods:

**Get:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
    {

        PopulateMachineTypeDropDownListStore();
        return View(await _context.Machines.AsNoTracking().ToListAsync());
    }
```

**Post:**

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Test")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> TestPost(int id, [Bind("Id,StoreID,PUnit,Status")] Machine machine)
    {
        if (id != machine.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                _context.Update(machine);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!MachineExists(machine.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(machine);}
```

The problem is that the class sent to the Post Action is null (almost all their fields are zero or null except for the Id)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestPost(int id, [Bind("Id,StoreID,PUnit,Status")] Machine machine)
```

**Question:** So, I don't know how to correct this. Could there be something missing in the view?

```
@model IEnumerable<Application.Models.Machine>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Test";

}
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <form asp-action="Test" asp-route-id="@item.Id" method="post">
        <table class="table">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@item.Id" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input asp-for="@item.MchName" readonly class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="@item.MchName" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <select asp-for="@item.StoreID" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.StoreID">
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="@item.StoreID" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input type="number" max="10" step=".1" asp-for="@item.PUnit" class="form-control" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="@item.PUnit" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <select name="Status" asp-for="@item.Status" class="form-control">
                                <option value="0">Operativo</option>
                                <option value="1">Nuevo Item</option>
                                <option value="2">Reparación</option>
                            </select>
                            <span asp-validation-for="@item.Status" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input id="submit-data" type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-default" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</form>}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you use asp.net or asp.net core? They are different frameworks

Comment: asp.net core. editing the tag now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the ModelBinder uses naming conventions for binding, try renaming the `machine` parameter of the `TestPost()` method to `item`.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> TestPost(
            int id, [Bind("Id, StoreID, PUnit,Status")] Machine item)
    {
        //... 
    }
```

Alternatively, in your View, you could rename the `item` variable to `machine`, so it matches the expected parameter name:

```
@foreach (var machine in Model)
{ ...  }
```

The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) describe this summarily:

> Model binding looks for the pattern parameter_name.property_name to bind values to properties

Lastly, leave out the `name` attribute in your Status dropdown, which would impede modelbinding. Just let `asp-for` do the work:

```
<select asp-for="@item.Status" class="form-control">
```

I don't really know how you fill the Store dropdown, but you should at least see the `PUnit` and `Status` properties being filled up this way.